# google youtube data api v3 youtube.videos.insert 503 error

Tags: youtube-api

youtube.videos.insert 503 error

yesterday I could upload video files. 
but today I cannot upload video files via google api v3

Uploading file...
A retriable HTTP error 503 occurred:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

503 means there was a transient error in YouTube server backend. Now it's working for me. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not really answering your question but it seems the '503' backend error is around at the moment. I'm having the same issue testing my iOS app using v3 objective-c YouTube API - I hit the same 503 error all the time, only 2-3 uploads out of 20 go through. Even the Google OS X sample app fails constantly. Definetely something in the backend... I've reported a bug to YouTube API a week ago.